# How to get rid of unwanted line - multiple table of contents in "report" class using titletoc package

Tags: table-of-contents, report, titletoc, multiple-files

I'm writing my thesis, and have stumbled upon a problem, I don't know how to fix.
I want two tables of contents - one for the actual thesis and one just before the appendix.
As the headline says, I'm writing in the report class with a separate file for each chapter of the thesis.

I have managed to get overleaf to create the two tables of contents that I want, but for some reason the first ends with a 'fun' line of the appendix content, while the last appendix table on contents starts with a line referencing to a bunch of chapters and sections. It's a little hard to explain - so I have attached some pictures - I have marked the unwanted lines with a red oval-thingy.

How can I get rid of these lines?
[image: Example of the unwanted line in the bottom of first table of content (the 'main' table)]

[image: Example of the unwanted line in top of second table of content (bilag = appendix)]

I have tried `\startcontents` and `\stopcontents`` without any changes happening.

Here is the code (since it is long document, I have narrowed it down to just a few chapters for exemplification):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Packages %
%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[noheader]{packages/sleek}
\usepackage{packages/sleek-title}
\usepackage{packages/sleek-theorems}
\usepackage{packages/sleek-listings}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document %
%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % default value for 'report' class is "2"
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\chapter*{Summary} 

\startcontents[main]
\printcontents[main]{}{-1}{\chapter*{Indholdsfortegnelse}}
%\romantableofcontents %commented out since it provides the full table of content including all chapters and sections of appendix - which is not wanted %
\chapter{Introduktion}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{Side \thepage \hspace{1pt} af \pageref{LastPage}}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Litteraturreview}
\lipsum[]
\chapter{Afhandlingens teorivalg}
\lipsum[]

\stopcontents[main]
\cleardoublepage
%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Appendix %
%%%%%%%%%%%%

\appendix

\chapter*{Bilagsoversigt}

\startcontents[bilag]
\printcontents[bilag]{}{-1}{}

\chapter{Interviewguides}
\lipsum[]

\chapter{Operationalisering af spørgeskema}
\lipsum[]
\section{SurveyXact spørgeskemaet}
\lipsum[]

\chapter{Kvalitativ analyse}
\section{Totaloversigt over NVivo koder}


\stopcontents[bilag]

\end{document}
```

I think the problem is something in the correlation between the sleek-packages and the titletoc, since the line doesn't show, if I remove the sleek-packages. But then I don't have the wished design of the document. So I seek a solution, where I can keep the sleek-packages for the document style.

If it's possible to get the first table of content (main document) to also contain the appendix-chapters (but not sections), that would be very nice.

If something needs to be elaborated please don't hesitate to tell me so, this is my first time posting a question - since the thesis is my first time working with overleaf.

Have a nice day and thanks in advance for any help :).

Comment: Please make sure to provide something others can test. Your example contains many files we do not have access to

Comment: @daleif I have removed the different files and replaced with `\lipsum[]`. Is it better now?

Comment: Well, you've narrowed down the problem.  But since `sleek` isn't in a normal TeX distribution, there's not much we can do.  What are the parts of `sleek` that you're interested in?

Comment: BTW: does this actually compile without errors in overleaf? We have seen multiple times that OL users overlook compilation errors because a PDF was created. The header in the image very much looks like the result of a compilation with errors.

Comment: I don't have that much insight in TeX, overleaf or `sleek`. It is basically something my thesis partner and I stumbled upon when starting the thesis project (https://da.overleaf.com/latex/templates/sleek-template/hrksrrdywhfk). We are both new to overleaf and we have just the style throughout the whole thesis, since we thought it looked nice and was easy enough to work with. 

I don't know if you can open this link: https://da.overleaf.com/project/60a3ab808b4e4885c9c87f55 - here I have combined the template from the link above with the code from this question.

Comment: The link is limited. Where in DK are you located? You could send a person invite to the doc to me via email: daleif@math.au.dk then I'll take a look. Or save the entire project as ZIP and send that to me.

Comment: Looking at the overleaf project the issue seems to be a badly coded template that loads a lot of packages including `hyperref` and thus if one adds packages later on things can go completely haywire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all comes down to https://da.overleaf.com/latex/templates/sleek-template/hrksrrdywhfk being a sub optimal template, or at least not explaining it self very well.

```
\usepackage[noheader]{packages/sleek}
```

loads a lot of packages, including several the OP is also loading later on. Included in this OPs list if `titletoc` but `packages/sleek`  autoloads `hyperref` and we all know that with a few exceptions `hyperref` should always be loaded last. Is `hyperref` last in `packages/sleek`? nope, but it did not end in catastrophe.

The issue here seems to be `titletoc` being loaded **after** `hyperref`. If we move all the OPs packages up above the `sleek` packages (and remove `biblatex` as `sleek` loads it), the project seems to at least compile without error.

That is, this seems to help

```
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{booktabs}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % sleek
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{comment}
% \usepackage{biblatex} % sleek
\usepackage{titletoc}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[noheader]{packages/sleek}
\usepackage{packages/sleek-title}
\usepackage{packages/sleek-theorems}
\usepackage{packages/sleek-listings}
```